# Что лучше использовать, uint или int в качестве аргумента функции, если значение должно быть >=0. Что использовать в качестве идентификатора?

Tags: c#, c++, типы-данных, типы

В чужом коде на C# нигде не встречаю `uint`, `ushort`, `ulong`. Если требуется строго положительный аргумент, то в начале функции обычно есть проверка с выбросом исключения, если аргумент отрицательный. Хотя аргумент мог бы быть положительным, если бы в функциях использовали `uint`.

Почему его не используют?

Почему не используют `uint` в качестве первичного ключа в таблице базы данных, если идентификатор все равно положительный (ни в одном из проектов я не видел отрицательных идентификаторов)?

Есть какая-то причина использовать обычный `int` вместо `uint`(`unsigned int`)?

Comment: «ни в одном из проектов я не видел отрицательных идентификаторов» — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1 знакомьтесь :D

Comment: Дух сообщества что ли?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Дело в том, что сборка, которая получается при компиляции, может быть использована другими языками, работающими на платформе .NET. В этих языках может и не быть беззнаковых целых чисел, и если публичные методы сборки содержат типы наподобие `uint`, вашу сборку невозможно будет использовать с такими языками. (Если сборка может работать со всеми языками под .NET, про неё говорят CLS-compliant.)

Если вы пишете библиотеку для «всего мира», то использование её из экзотических языков — неплохая цель, поэтому такие библиотеки часто ограничены в использовании типов. Если же вы пишете код для себя, или не пишете библиотеку, то по идее можно использовать любой подходящий тип.

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваша сборка была совместима с другими языками, проще всего дать ей атрибут `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` (прописывается в любом файле, снаружи классов, например, в `Assembly.cs`), и компилятор сам предупредит о нарушениях. Подробная документация [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components).

Comment: Чисто для общего развития: а в чём ещё обычно самоорганичивают такие проекты, помимо unsigned типов?

Comment: @AK: В CLS-compliant-библиотеке не должно быть имён, которые отличаются лишь регистром, т. к. например Visual Basic является нечувствительным к регистру.

Comment: @AK: Полный список тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components

Comment: @AK: Проще всего дать сборке атрибут `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` и посмотреть, на что наругается компилятор.

Comment: Просветите не знающего платформу, в каких языках нету uint?

Comment: @andreymal: ЕМНИП, старый VB поддерживал только знаковые типы (новый уже поддерживает и беззнаковые).

Answer (score 3):

Многие базы данных (н.п. MSSQL) не поддерживают беззнаковые типы. Но использование целочисленных счётчиков в качестве первичного ключа - это в любом случае плохая идея, так как работает ровно до того момента, когда часть базы уезжает во внешнюю среду (другая база данных, файл, бэкап). После этого взаимодействие между этими компонентами ведёт к коллизиям, приходится заводить таблицы мапингов с соответствием номеров. Вместо этого в качестве уникального идентификатора записи лучше использовать GUID.

Беззнаковые типы ты можешь использовать во внутреннем коде, но не стоит тащить эти значения в публичные интерфейсы. Их просто будет сложно интегрировать с прочим окружением. В .NET не принято использовать беззнаковые величины и ты не сможешь ни обратиться к элементу коллекции, ни прочитать несколько байт из потока без необходимости кастить твои беззнаковые значения к знаковым.

Сами же разработчики оставляют отрицательные значения для всевозможных магических чисел и флагов. Например, `Stream.ReadByte()` возвращает не `byte`, а `int`, так как в случае неожиданного конца потока вернёт -1.

Но в итоге всё сводится к тому, что это просто непринято, да и мир, стараниями Java, всё дальше уходит от беззнаковых типов.

Comment: Ну, поведение `Stream.ReadByte` «одолжено» у C, а более современные интерфейсы всё же возвращают точный тип (да тот же `Stream.Read`).